# Edit Out Bits of Variables in a C# Program

Tags: c#, string, replace

How can I edit out unneeded parts of variables in a given C# script?
For example, for the code:

```
var Variable1 = "the big lazy fox"
```

I would like to change to something like:

```
var Variable1 = "lazy fox"
```

EDIT: Let me myself clearer, the variable in question is updated every two minutes with a new string, and the first two words need to be edited out, which are always the same. There is no permanent set piece of text for the given variable (in its original state).

Comment: I am sorry, but there is no such option in Visual Express?

Comment: @addon101 Yes there is, it's part of the `String` class which is the same no matter which version of Visual Studio you're using (as are all other framework classes). Express just gives you less tools, not a limited version of the language

Comment: Ok, sorry, i found it in the end, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A q[uick google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=replace%20string%20contents%20c%23) would have given you this answer much faster, but here you go.

```
var Variable1 = "The quick brown fox";
Variable1 = Variable1.Replace("brown", string.Empty);
```

`Variable1` now equals `"The quick fox"`

Answer (score 0):

```
var Variable1 = "The quick brown fox";
var Variable2 = String.Join(" ", Variable1.Split(' ').Skip(2));
```

Should do the trick

Broken down, this means... Take the input string, split it into words (based on the spaces). Skip the first two words, then join the rest of the words together using spaces.

This will work for any input that has more than two words.

Comment: In this example, wouldn't you want to use `String.Join(" ", Variable1.Split(' ').Skip(2));` to better clarify that you are splitting the original string?

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Good catch. I was initially using `Input`/`Output` then edited to use Var1/2 as per the question and missed that.